# libtorrent module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, libtorrent

I use this code to download from torrent to drive using google colab

```
1   !apt install python3-libtorrent
2
3   import libtorrent as lt
4 
5   ses = lt.session()
6   ses.listen_on(6881, 6891)
7   downloads = []
```

It runs out an error in line 3 saying:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libtorrent'
```

The complete output is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-libtorrent is already the newest version (1.1.5-1build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1098f0f9d9d1> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().system('apt install python3-libtorrent')
      2 
----> 3 import libtorrent as lt
      4 
      5 ses = lt.session()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libtorrent'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried using pip instead of apt and it didn't work.
There was another error saying:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-libtorrent (from versions: none)
No matching distribution found for python3-libtorrent

The output was

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-libtorrent (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python3-libtorrent
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-b9ec203eb952> in <module>()
      1 get_ipython().system('pip install python3-libtorrent')
      2 
----> 3 import libtorrent as lt
      4 
      5 ses = lt.session()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libtorrent'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: use `pip` instead of `apt`. I'm not sure why apt doesn't work, but pip definitely should

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly follow the below given YouTube link. This would be helpful to you.

https://youtu.be/kFG2YHVGZLs

In short, just add the following two lines before "!apt install python3-libtorrent"

!python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

!python -m pip install lbry-libtorrent

Comment: Could you please also post a summary of the solution as part of your answer, so in case the link changes or is taken down, users can still find the relevant answer?